# Comparing Variable with Number

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The following code throws an error and I have no clue why it happens.

```
#! /bin/bash

# This script checks if your Apache log is older than two weeks.
# If so, the files will be deleted

# Defining savepath
savePath="/var/log/test.log"

# Startup
printf "\n*** Starting logrotate at $(date +'%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S') ***" >> $savePath

# Check if Apache logs older than two weeks are existing
apacheCount=`sudo /usr/bin/find /var/log/apache2/ -iname "access.log.*.gz" -mtime +15 | wc -l`

# If so, delete 'em!
if [ "$apacheCount" != "0" ]; then

    sudo /usr/bin/find /var/log/apache2/ -iname "access.log.*.gz" -mtime +8 -exec rm -f {} \;
    newValue=sudo /usr/bin/find /var/log/apache2/ -iname "access.log.*.gz" -mtime +15 | wc -l

    if [ "$newValue" == "0" ]; then
            printf "\n$(date +'%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S'): $apacheCount Apache Log(s) has / have been deleted." >> $savePath
    else
            printf "\n$(date +'%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S'): There was an error. $(($apacheCount-$newValue)) items were not deleted." >> $savePath
    fi
else
    printf "\n$(date +'%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S'): No Apache Log older than two weeks found." >> $savePath
fi
```

When executing the program it throws the following error:

> [: unexpected operator
>
> arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "1-"

I am relatively new to bash so I would appreciate it if you could explain where I went wrong.

Comment: `newValue=sudo /usr/bin/find /var/log/apache2/ -iname "access.log.*.gz" -mtime +15 | wc -l` is going to be a problem. Instead `newValue=$(sudo /usr/bin/find /var/log/apache2/ -iname "access.log.*.gz" -mtime +15 | wc -l)` to capture the output of the `wc -l` into the variable.

Comment: Also, dump this thing into https://www.shellcheck.net/ It will tell you everything wrong with it and suggestions for improvements.

Comment: @JNevill: `shellcheck` (or the online service) will tell you *some* of the things wrong with it.  I'll be impressed if it works out why `newValue` isn't set, as the errant command is perfectly valid - just not what was intended.

Comment: @TobySpeight I agree, but it will tell you that `newvalue` isn't set which is a HUGE clue here.

Comment: I don't see how the code you copied to your question could produce the error you copied, since it does not do a numeric comparison. If you want to do numetic comparison, you need to use `-ne` and `-eq` instead of `==` and `!=`, which are string comparison. With bash, its better is to use `((...))` or at least `[[...]]`.

Answer (score 0):

The line below had an error, `` added

```
newValue=`sudo /usr/bin/find /var/log/apache2/ -iname "access.log.*.gz" -mtime +15 | wc -l`
```

Improved code:

```
#! /bin/bash

# This script checks if your Apache log is older than two weeks.
# If so, the files will be deleted

# Defining savepath
savePath="/var/log/test.log"

# Startup
printf "\n*** Starting logrotate at $(date +'%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S') ***" >> $savePath

# Check if Apache logs older than two weeks are existing
apacheCount=`sudo /usr/bin/find /var/log/apache2/ -iname "access.log.*.gz" -mtime +15 | wc -l`

# If so, delete 'em!
if [ "$apacheCount" != "0" ]; then

   sudo /usr/bin/find /var/log/apache2/ -iname "access.log.*.gz" -mtime +8 -exec rm -f {} \;
   #the line below had an error, `` added
   newValue=`sudo /usr/bin/find /var/log/apache2/ -iname "access.log.*.gz" -mtime +15 | wc -l`

   if [ "$newValue" == "0" ]; then
        printf "\n$(date +'%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S'): $apacheCount Apache Log(s) has / have been deleted." >> $savePath
   else
        printf "\n$(date +'%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S'): There was an error. $(($apacheCount-$newValue)) items were not deleted." >> $savePath
   fi
else
   printf "\n$(date +'%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S'): No Apache Log older than two weeks found." >> $savePath
fi
```

Comment: Did you mean to leave the `==` that `[` complained about?  The code, while "improved", certainly isn't *fixed*.

Comment: Instead of backticks, it would be better to use `newvalue=$(command)`

Comment: @TobySpeight Gracias. fixed comment.

Comment: @TobySpeight  It's a new bash thing.  You CAN use `==` or just `=` these days.

Comment: Thank you for making improvements to my code! When I use `bash ./logrotate.sh` instead of `sh` it won't throw the "unexpected operator"-error for some reason and the program keeps running fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in your script you are wrongly capturing the value in `newValue`. Modify below two line in your code which is fix the issue:-

```
#better use below syntax
apacheCount=$(sudo /usr/bin/find /var/log/apache2/ -iname "access.log.*.gz" -mtime +15 | wc -l)


newValue=$(sudo /usr/bin/find /var/log/apache2/ -iname "access.log.*.gz" -mtime +15 | wc -l)
```